# Estimate battery's real capacity in real time

Tags: power, electrical-engineering, batteries

The maximum capacity of a battery during usage can vary from manufacturer's specifications due to factors like temperatures and battery health. Because of that i want to estimate the real maximum capacity (in kWh) of a battery using the percentage of the battery's remaining capacity (in %) and the current power consumption (in kW).

I will get the above mentioned measurements in real time, in a time interval of every second, i.e., in a time series. During data recording, i will never see a full battery charge cycle but instead the battery will be between ~95% and ~35% percent.

In my data exploration, i cumulated the current power consumption, visualized it together with the battery percentage and noticed that they share a linear dependency, as you can see in figure 1.

**Figure 1: progression of battery capacity percentage and cumulated power consumption**
[image]

My approach of holding measurements in a bin for every 2% lost battery capacity and performing on that bin a linear regression to predict the cumulated power consumption at zero percent battery capacity is giving me rather unstable results. (see figure 2)

**Figure 2: estimated capacity of every two percent battery capacity**
[image]

- Is there a way to get the results in a more stable (less varying) state?
- Or is there even a more exact way to estimate the current maximum capacity of the battery using a different method?

Answer (score 1):

I actually did this for a battery control driver for a tablet. The only way I found to do it was to take manufacturers charge/discharge curves as functions of temperature and number of cycles and encode them by hand in a lookup table.
This does assume that the manufacturer has enough data, the data is accurate, and is willing to supply it.